# Inverse navigation property in base class in EF6 core

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core

I have the following model structure in EF6.

Base class `Property`:

```
public abstract class Property
{
    .....
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Linked to `Product` model class:

```
public class Product
{
    ....
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public Property Property { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Now I have some inherited classes from `Property` on of which:

```
public class DateProperty : Property
{
    ....
}
```

Now when I generate the migration I get this error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'DateProperty.Products' of type 'List'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

What am I doing wrong? If it is using TPH pattern it should just link to a single table.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I tested your code and Hasn't Problem,can you share Whole Classes and DbContext

Comment: Nothing special in other things just normal attributes of each class

Comment: The error message is referring to '**DateProperty**.Products', which should not happen (`Products` are navigation property of abstract `Property` entity, not derived entities) in case you are not redefining it with something not shown here (fluent API, attributes, shadow property etc.). You really need to provide reproducible example, the current is not enough as mentioned in the other comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I found out the issue, The problem is that the error message is misleading and should not refer to the child class.
It turned out that I have mistakenly defined two references of type `Property` inside the class `Product`, so it was not able to find which one to use.